# How to create breadcrumb menus in a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am planning to incorporate a breadcrumb menu into my website. I basically have a sidebar menu with submenus, which I also want to setup as a breadcrumb menu.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What kind of website are you talking about?  If you're working with a forum-like system [blogs, wordpress], or a directory view, this'll be easy.  If you have a ton of pages with no real organization location-wise, this has to be done manually.

Comment: It's currently a HTML website which will eventually be a WordPress site

Comment: As interesting as the general theme is, this question is too broad to be answerable, and does not work with Stack Overflow's Q&A format. It is very old, so it would be best closed rather than repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on [Smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/20/50-new-css-techniques-for-your-next-web-design/) that talks about breadcrumbs

Here's a search result for breadcrumbs at [smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/search-results/?q=creating+breadcrumbs&submit=Go!&client=pub-6779860845561969&forid=1&channel=3942503296&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&flav=0000&sig=ZKMPj-qL6g57hzX6&cof=LH:50;LW:138;L:http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/wp-content/themes/default-autosvn-stable//img/logo.gif;S:http://www.smashingmagazine.com;FORID:11&hl=en&sitesearch=&sitesearch=www.smashingmagazine.com)